# .NET Core: using System.Drawing.Common on Linux in Docker - "Could not open display" error

Tags: linux, .net-core, x11, system.drawing

I have code ported onto .NET Core that uses System.Drawing. Currently it seems System.Drawing.Common from corefx [supports](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20712) Linux.
But I have difficulties with running my code on Linux.

Particularly I'm getting:

> NotSupportedException "Could not open display (X-Server required. Check your DISPLAY environment variable)"

for this code:

```
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
```

Previously I was getting

> DllNotFoundException "Unable to load DLL 'libX11': The specified
>   module or one of its dependencies could not be found.\n (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

with stacktrace:

```
   at System.Drawing.LibX11Functions.XOpenDisplay(IntPtr display)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr hwnd)
   at mycode
```

But this issue I fixed by installing `libx11-dev` package.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
ENV DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE true

# install libgdiplus for System.Drawing
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated libgdiplus libc6-dev

# install x11 for System.Drawing
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated libx11-dev
```

So what can I do with "Could not open display (X-Server required. Check your DISPLAY environment variable)" error?

Comment: Can you run normal X11 programs like xterm?

Comment: You need at least `libgdiplus` and all its dependencies. Overall, use a true portable solution like SkiaSharp would be a much better alternative,https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp

Comment: @n.m. it's inside Docker. Should mentioned it

Comment: @LexLi I had liggdiplus installed

Comment: You should move the "inside Docker" part to your question body. It does explain why it fails as when Mono guys created `libgdiplus` and their `System.Drawing` (Microsoft .NET Core borrows the same concepts), there was never a restricted environment like Docker. Stack Overflow cannot help much, as you need the original developers to help or you hack the code base yourself.

Comment: thanks for downvoting, it helps very much (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can use an image-based `Graphics`, rather than an window-based. Something like this:

```cs
var g = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
```

Comment: But we can we do if we don't want to raster the image? (to keep it a vector image..)